# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment while extracting replies on tweet (conversation_id)

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I am using the following code [from this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/mining-replies-to-tweets-a-walkthrough-9a936602c4d6) to extract the replies on a tweet using its conversation_id. The code is working fine, but just for the conversations of the last week.
**NOTE: I am using Academic Track credentials of Twitter API**, therefore it should not happen.

```
consumer_key= "----"
consumer_secret= "----"
access_token_key= "----"
access_token_secret= "----"

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret, api_version='2')

class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        """data is a tweet's json object"""
        self.data = data
        self.children = []

    def id(self):
        """a node is identified by its author"""
        return self.data['author_id']

    def reply_to(self):
        """the reply-to user is the parent of the node"""
        return self.data['in_reply_to_user_id']

    def find_parent_of(self, node):
        """append a node to the children of it's reply-to user"""
        if node.reply_to() == self.id():
            self.children.append(node)
            return True
        for child in self.children:
            if child.find_parent_of(node):
                return True
        return False

    def print_tree(self, level):
        """level 0 is the root node, then incremented for subsequent generations"""
        # print(f'{level*"_"}{level}: {self.id()}')
        level += 1
        for child in self.children:
            child.print_tree(level)

    def list_l1(self):
        conv_id = []
        child_id = []
        text = []
        # print(self.data['id'])
        for child in self.children:
            conv_id.append(self.data['id'])
            child_id.append(child.data['id'])
            text.append(child.data['text'])
        return conv_id, child_id, text

"""
Retrieves level 1 replies for a given conversation id
Returns lists conv_id, child_id, text tuple which shows every reply's tweet_id and text in the last two lists
"""
def retrieve_replies(conversation_id):
    try:
        # GET ROOT OF THE CONVERSATION
        r = api.request(f'tweets/:{conversation_id}',
                        {
                            'tweet.fields': 'author_id,conversation_id,created_at,in_reply_to_user_id'
                        },hydrate_type=HydrateType.APPEND)

        for item in r:
            root = TreeNode(item)
            # print(f'ROOT {root.id()}')

        # GET ALL REPLIES IN CONVERSATION

        pager = TwitterPager(api, 'tweets/search/recent',
                             {
                                 'query': f'conversation_id:{conversation_id}',
                                 'tweet.fields': 'author_id,conversation_id,created_at,in_reply_to_user_id'
                             },hydrate_type=HydrateType.APPEND)

        orphans = []

        for item in pager.get_iterator(wait=2):
            node = TreeNode(item)
            # print(f'{node.id()} => {node.reply_to()}')
            # COLLECT ANY ORPHANS THAT ARE NODE'S CHILD
            orphans = [orphan for orphan in orphans if not node.find_parent_of(orphan)]
            # IF NODE CANNOT BE PLACED IN TREE, ORPHAN IT UNTIL ITS PARENT IS FOUND
            if not root.find_parent_of(node):
                orphans.append(node)

        conv_id, child_id, text = root.list_l1()
#         print('\nTREE...')
#       root.print_tree(0)

        assert len(orphans) == 0, f'{len(orphans)} orphaned tweets'

    except TwitterRequestError as e:
        print(e.status_code)
        for msg in iter(e):
            print(msg)

    except TwitterConnectionError as e:
        print(e)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return conv_id, child_id, text

def reply_thread_maker(conv_ids):
    conv_id = []
    child_id = []
    text = []
    for id in conv_ids:
        conv_id1, child_id1, text1 = retrieve_replies(id)
        conv_id.extend(conv_id1)
        child_id.extend(child_id1)
        text.extend(text1)

    replies_data = {'conversation_id' : conv_id,
               'child_tweet_id': child_id,
               'tweet_text' : text}

    replies= pd.DataFrame(replies_data)
    return replies
```

Here I am passing the **conversation_id**; with this id it works fine -> `conv_ids = ['1475262305898311681']` ; meanwhile with the following:

```
conv_ids = ['1215360885692210000']
replies = reply_thread_maker(conv_ids)
replies.head()
```

It gives the following error:

```
local variable 'root' referenced before assignment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ANEESB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18696/3887234826.py in <module>
----> 1 replies = reply_thread_maker(conv_ids)
      2 # WRITE REPLIES TO FILE
      3 #VIEW SAMPLE REPLIES
      4 replies.head()

C:\Users\ANEESB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18696/2579331657.py in reply_thread_maker(conv_ids)
     58     text = []
     59     for id in conv_ids:
---> 60         conv_id1, child_id1, text1 = retrieve_replies(id)
     61         conv_id.extend(conv_id1)
     62         child_id.extend(child_id1)

C:\Users\ANEESB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18696/2579331657.py in retrieve_replies(conversation_id)
     51         print(e)
     52 
---> 53     return conv_id, child_id, text
     54 
     55 def reply_thread_maker(conv_ids):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'conv_id' referenced before assignment
```

Can someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If exceptions are raised you end up with a `return` statement that references a `conv_id` that may not yet exist. An exception is raised because `root` is used before assignment and the reason that may happen is that `for item in r:` may not iterate if `r` is empty and therefore nothing is ever assigned to  `root`.

Solution:

- check if `r` contains something and either raise an exception or return something - but make sure the method exists at that point
- do not continue to a regular `return` after an exception is raised.

Comment: I used another ```conv_id``` (from 2020) which, I confirmed, received a reply. But root still returns nothing on that, how should I proceed with it to achieve the objective?